# Compare 2 CSVs and write the difference to file

Tags: python, csv, compare

Hi I'm having an issue where i need to compare 2 CSV files and write the the rows that are in csv2 that aren't in csv1. i'm still getting used to python and just need a guide to get in the right direction for this problem.

Comment: You can probably use python **pandas**. It's a library for data manipulation and analysis which will be useful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f1, open('file2.csv', 'r') as f2:
    fileone = f1.readlines()
    filetwo = f2.readlines()

with open('file3.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outfile.write(line)
```